# Implementing Angular Universal for Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am trying to implement Server Side Rendering in my Angular App by running the command

ng add @ng-toolkit/universal

but as soon as I run this command I get below error

ERROR: newTree.optimize is not a function
ERROR: If you think that this error shouldn't occur, please fill up bug report here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/new
INFO: stacktrace has been sent to tracking system.
Nothing to be done.

Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: Have a look here https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/776

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
$ ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {{ name of your project }}
```

This command will install the required packages and add various files required for setting up SSR:

```
src/main.server.ts,
src/app/app.server.module.ts,
tsconfig.server.json,
webpack.server.config.js,
server.ts,
```

It will also update the following files accordingly:

```
package.json,
angular.json,
src/main.ts,
src/app/app.module.ts
```

The command will also spin up an Express server for you. Open the server.ts file; you should see the following code:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

As you can see folder set to the dist/browser folder that contains the client-side bundle and which is created when the app is built. The server listens by default on the 4000 port and intercepts the possible requests for fetching HTML and static files.

Universal applications make use of the @angular/platform-server
package instead of @angular/platform-browser, which allows you to deliver Angular apps from the server.

In the Express server, requests from the client for fetching application pages are handled by the ngExpressEngine. This simply works by calling the renderModuleFactory() function.

Head back to your terminal, make sure you are inside your Angular project and run the following commands:

```
npm run build:ssr 
npm run serve:ssr
```

Comment: I asked regarding different library

Comment: I asked regarding @ng-toolkit/universal library and not @nguniversal/express-engine